# Override all background image except background image with url

Tags: css

In the code below, I want to override the background image for `.box` but not for `.foo`. I want to override all `background-image` except ones which has an image as the property.

`liner-gradient`, `gradient` should be overriden but not `url`.

But I want to do this using some generic code, as the content is dynamic and I can't predict all the class names.

Any way I can do this only using CSS?

```
.box {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow);
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.foo {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTqy1uodNithL90ttojytSP2imO4RC1y3qlm_ebZdRmNWh_8juV9Q');
}

* {
  // override here.
}
```

Comment: override you mean disable them? or place something else instead?

Comment: Would writing "background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow);" as "background: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow);" instead help, so that you are only targeting "background-image"?

Comment: @CarolMcKay background is the shorthand that include background-image so targeting background-image will also affect background

Comment: do all the boxes have to be divs? <section> have a linear-gradient, while <div> have url backgrounds, then you won't target section but will target div and not concern yourself with class names.

Comment: @CarolMcKay its not that specific. thing is i'm trying to build a global dark theme for chrome. So it has to be a bit more generic.

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
* { background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow); }

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  * { background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTqy1uodNithL90ttojytSP2imO4RC1y3qlm_ebZdRmNWh_8juV9Q'); }
}
```

Reference material: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme